# Evaluating a boolean to true or false within a for loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, for-loop, angular6

The issue I am having is related to using a boolean fvalue and turning it to true or false in the event that a string include the string unlimited. The issue is that I am also appending a subscription to an area of values and I require use of an *NgIf to change the pages rendering using this boolean.

```
<span tabindex="0" *ngIf="isUnlimitedPlan">{{ data2.datas2 }}</span>
<span tabindex="0" *ngIf="!isUnlimitedPlan">{{ data2.datas2 }} monthly minutes</span>
```

Here is where the issue is.

```
isUnlimitedPlan:boolean;
this.availablePlansResponse.planPackage.planGroupMap.flexPlans[0].planCategories[0].plans.forEach(
(currentElement, index) => {
this.isUnlimitedPlan = currentElement.monthlyMinutes.includes(
'Unlimited'
);
this.genericDataPlans[index].title2 =
currentElement.planDisplayName;
this.genericDataPlans[index].datas2 = currentElement.monthlyMinutes;
this.genericDataPlans[index].price2 =
currentElement.finalMonthlyFee;
this.genericDataPlans[index].desc2 = currentElement.categoryId;
}
);
```

Comment: I do not see the subscription. Can you add it? 
Also, can you explain better the problem? Is your problem that the ```isUnlimitedPlan``` is not getting updated in the HTML?

Comment: yes that is the problem  isUnlimitedPlan is not getting updated in the HTML.

Comment: Why are you not doing `this.genericDataPlans[index].isUnlimitedPlan = ` ? That is to set this value for each plan?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. Can you add the subscription? Also, Can you add the full component (.ts and html)?

Comment: Well the issue is that the boolean evaluates to true or false given the string ' Ulimited ' is not included in the property monthlyMinutes. If it is cluded ideally the isUnlimited will be set to true and false if it is not.

Answer (score 1):

some like?

```
<span tabindex="0">{{ data2.datas2 }}
     {{data2.monthlyMinutes.includes('Unlimited')?'':'monthly minutes'}}</span>
```

NOTE: I use an unique line, simply add 'monthly minutes' or not according the value of data2.monthlyMinutes